# UserController in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I can''t find the UserController in a new Laravel project. I have tried to create the controller my self, but I still get this error: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\User' not found

Here is my code in UsersController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class UsersController extends Controller
{
    //
}
```

It is Laravel 7.12.0

Comment: Can you share the code of the line this error occurs (any maybe a bit around it) since the code you show doesn't produce the error.

Comment: The `UserController` or `UsersController` isn't part of the Laravel framework or the `laravel/ui` package.

Comment: Your error is `UserController` but you are sharing code for `UsersController` (different name). I'm assuming that `UserController` genuinely does not exist?

Comment: Could try a `composer dumpautoload`

Answer (score 1):

Class `App\Http\Controllers\User` It's not the same as `App\Http\Controllers\UsersController` that's why his mistake. You have to aim for the right controller on your route.

Answer (score 0):

To create your UserController in laravel, you have to type this command in your terminal :

```
php artisan make:controller UserController
```

To create an other controller :

```
php artisan make:controller <controller-name>
```